# UIView with Tap Gesture Segue

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, segue, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a smaller `UIView` as a subview to the main `UIView` on my `UIViewController`.  This smaller `UIView` also has an image and a couple of labels.

What I want is for the user to touch this smaller view (anywhere on this view or it's contents) and then segue to a new `UIViewController`.

I have added a Tap Gesture to the smaller view and set a segue from the Tap Gesture to the `UIViewController` I want to show next.

However this only works if the user touches only a space on the view that does not have the labels or image and "User Interaction Enabled" is checked.  If the image or labels are touched, nothing happens, and if "User Interaction Enabled" is unchecked, nothing happens.

I've done this entirely from the storyboard, and only implementing a `prepareForSegue` method.

Is there something I'm missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Why not just place a transparent button over the UIViewController & all its views that triggers the segue

Comment: @RyanG  I honestly had not thought of that.  That would make things a lot easier!  Thanks, I'll try that and see how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the user Interaction from all the Labels and images(uiimageview has userinterraction set no by default). If other elements have user interaction enabled, they will catch the touch; if they have user interaction set to no, the next view in hierachy will catch it.

Very important is to remove the interaction from the labels and imageviews, not the view you are touching

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, set the `UIView` with user interaction enabled, and then set all of it's child items (the labels and image) to not have user interaction enabled.

Comment: Aye, that would be it

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just place a transparent button over the UIViewController & all its views that triggers the segue. That way you don't need to worry about any views under it

Comment: That's a very ugly approach^^. What was the answer if he asked about pan or swipe

Comment: Well if there are no swipe or pan gestures needed, I don't see the downside. He did not mention swipe or pan.

Comment: The important matter here is to teach him to handle the touches correctly, not to hack a wierd solution;

Comment: Yes I see what you mean... but I wouldn't call placing a button on top of your views a 'hack'. It is much easier to wire up a IBAction for a UIButton touch than to create a tapGesture listener and set the userInteractionEnabled to NO for each subview in the UIView.. IMO at least.

Comment: @RyanG  I tried this, and although it's easy to implement and to get everything I needed done accomplished, I then had to make sure that the button would handle the same way as the `UIView` with autolayout and otherwise, which was more of a hassle than I want to deal with right now.  I will most likely use this suggestion in the future for some things, but if I can use the stuff I already have in place right now, the better it is for me.  Thank you for your suggestion.  It WAS helpful.